# Generating JSON with output dates

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

Given the following case class:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
case class ReportDateVO(reportDate: LocalDate)
```

I'm trying to define the implicit json format:

```
implicit val reportDatesWrite : Writes[ReportDateVO] = (
      (JsPath \ "dt").write[LocalDate]
  ) (unlift(ReportDateVO.unapply))
```

But I get the following error:

> overloaded method value write with alternatives: (t:
>   java.time.LocalDate)(implicit w:
>   play.api.libs.json.Writes[java.time.LocalDate])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
>    (implicit w:
>   play.api.libs.json.Writes[java.time.LocalDate])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[java.time.LocalDate]
>   cannot be applied to (fdic.ReportDateVO ⇒ java.time.LocalDate)

What are these alternatives? there's no default format? how to fix this? I'm using Play 2.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can only use JSON combinators for case classes with minimum number of parameters 2 (up to 22). Look at the docs for [JSON Reads/Writes/Format Combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Complex-Reads), section **Complex Reads**. The combinators work similarly for Reads and Writes so short explanation in **Complex Reads** section might be helpful. So basically what compiler says to you is that you cannot pass function of type **fdic.ReportDateVO ⇒ java.time.LocalDate** to the method ***write*** what is kind of weird, because logically, if you have parentheses around the ***(JsPath \ "dt").write[LocalDate]***, which should return instance of **OWrites[LocalDate]**, the compiler should complain about wrong ***apply*** method in object of type **OWrites[LocalDate]**.

I think the best alternative (if you want to have custom filed name) is to implement **Writes[LocalDate]** manually.

```
implicit val reportDatesWrite: Writes[ReportDateVO] = OWrites[ReportDateVO] {
  rdvo: ReportDateVO => Json.obj(
    "dt" -> DefaultLocalDateWrites.writes(rdvo.reportDate)
  )
}
```

If field name can match the name of parameter in case class (reportDate) then you also can use Play helper method which is implemented using Scala macros.

```
implicit val reportDatesWrite: Writes[ReportDateVO] = Json.writes[ReportDateVO]
```

Comment: When I try to use DefaultLocalDateWrites I get an error message that the function is not found.I'm importing play.api.libs.json._ that includes LocalWrites, any ideas?

Comment: Try to import it directly `import play.api.libs.json.Writes.DefaultLocalDateWrites`. It is a part of `play.api.libs.json.DefaultWrites` which is mixed in to `play.api.libs.json.Writes` companion object. Or just import everything `play.api.libs.json.Writes._`

Answer (score 1):

PlayJson only provides serializers for basic types like Int, String, Double - LocalDate isn't one of them.

You have the right idea, but need to be more specific and define Combinator for LocalDate first:

```
   implicit val LocalDateWrites: Writes[LocalDate] = Writes {
        (l: LocalDate) => JsString(l.toString())
   }

    implicit val reportDatesWrite : Writes[ReportDateVO] = (
        (JsPath \ "dt").write[LocalDate]
    ) (unlift(ReportDateVO.unapply))
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error in the reportDatesWrite: overloaded method value write with alternatives: (t: java.time.LocalDate)(implicit w: play.api.libs.json.Writes[java.time.LocalDate])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] <and> (implicit w: play.api.libs.json.Writes[java.time.LocalDate])play.api.libs.json.OWrites[java.time.LocalDate] cannot be applied to (fdic.ReportDateVO ⇒ java.time.LocalDate)